# Network status icon vpn start / configure not working

Tags: wireless, networking, icons, vpn

i just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and installed my VPN.  everything was fine yesterday, yet today i can't click on the wifi icon in the task bar and select my vpn, or the configure vpn options.  when i select these menu items on the wifi right click menu nothing happens.  the connect option should animate the wifi icon and then add the lock indicator when it is done.  however nothing happens.   and the same goes for the configure vpn menu option.  when i select it nothing happens.

i can go to my network control panel and activate the vpn, and the configuration both from there just fine.  it is only the right click menu on the wifi icon that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is more of a workaround, logging out and back in worked for me.

There is a bug located [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1297849) that talks about a related issue that may be the cause.

Comment: This is a bug and should have been flagged as one.

Comment: I've gone through all the comments and my problems EXACTLY correlate with the problem people are having.  Waiting for a fix too I guess?